# Puppet Master Server Fails to Start Out of No Where

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I've search around and have not found an answer that worked so I thought I would try to see if there are any Puppet Masters out there that can guide me.

Seemingly out of no where my Puppet Master server services are simply failing to start and I can't figure out why.

I did note that the puppet user had vanished (no sure why yet)

I recreated the user which cleared the error I was getting that the user was missing.

Now when I issue

`systemctl start puppetserver.service`

I get

`Job for puppetserver.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status puppetserver.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.`

The status shows

```
puppetserver.service - LSB: puppetserver

   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/puppetserver; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2018-05-22 09:41:53 MDT; 29s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 4157 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/puppetserver start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
May 22 09:41:53 oraws-puppet1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: puppetserver...
May 22 09:41:53 oraws-puppet1 systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 22 09:41:53 oraws-puppet1 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: puppetserver.
May 22 09:41:53 oraws-puppet1 systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Unit entered failed state.
May 22 09:41:53 oraws-puppet1 systemd[1]: puppetserver.service: Failed with result exit-code.
```

The system us Ubuntu 16.04. 16gb of mem. Dedicated server so 10gb is given to Java.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the `puppet` user has vanished then that in itself is a plausible explanation for the master not starting.  You could consider checking the system log for any messages Puppet may have emitted about the problem.  In any case, I would suggest backing up your config files, SSL certs, and manifest set, and then reinstalling Puppet.

Comment: I did just that in the end. A full rebuild which might have exposed the original issue. I think it was an update to the latest Puppet. First step is to download the puppet-release-pce-trusty.deb and use dpkg etc. After the re-install I got the exact same error when trying to start the service. The only way I got back was using the .deb file that was used to originally build the system. I think there is a problem with the latest Puppet and Ubuntu 16.04. Not completely 100% sure but it sure seems that way